# Is it possible to use vector drawables in Nativescript as Image source?

Tags: android, nativescript, android-vectordrawable

I'm creating Nativesctript Angular app for Android. I used vector drawables (downloaded from [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/)) in `iconSource` of `tabItem` and they work ok. But I also tried to use same icon like this:

```
<Image src="res://account_multiple" width="20" height="20"></Image>
```

And only blank space is shown. The icon is under `/res/drawable/` and is shown in tab without problem.

I tried to find answer in docs or other forums but couldn't find anything. I downloaded sources for Nativescript and Nativescript Angular and noticed that images are loaded differently for `Image` and for `tabItem`, but I don't know Android enough to know if the method used in `Image` makes it impossible to use vector drawables.

So am I doing something wrong or should I use `png` icons always for `Image`?

Comment: What's the minimum Android version you want to support? Vector Drawables work only on Android 5.0 and later. Also may I know why don't you consider using font icons / svg that would work for both platforms (iOS & Android)?

Comment: @Manoj 5.0+ is not a problem for me. Vector drawables are only supported on Android? Didn't know that (although I create the app only for Android for now). SVG are ok too. So I'll try if they will work with such syntax. For icon fonts, I couldn't find one with all icons I needed and I had some problems with making them work with `TabView`.

Comment: Yes, vector drawables are Android only feature. SVG should work for both iOS & Android. It's quite impossible to find all icons at one place, so you may prefer to create your own font by combining icons from different font files or even include your own SVG - Try http://fontastic.me/ You may use [nativescript-vector-icons](https://github.com/manojdcoder/nativescript-vector-icons) plugin to add font icons to TabView / ActionBar.